# Show only three significant digits for the data volume

Tags: vb.net

how can I Show only three significant digits for the data volume, i.e. 0,xxx; x,xx; xx,x; xxx; x’xxx etc.

this is my code

```
Option Strict On

Imports System.Globalization

Module Module1

    Public Function BytesToMegabytes(Bytes As Long) As String
        'This function gives an estimate to two decimal
        'places.  For a more precise answer, format to
        'more decimal places or just return dblAns

        Dim dblAns As Double = (Bytes / 1024) / 1024

        Dim ci = New CultureInfo("en-GB")
        ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = "'"

        Return dblAns.ToString("###,###,##0.00", ci)

    End Function

    Sub Main()

        Console.WriteLine(BytesToMegabytes(9225936896))

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

**Outputs:**
**currently I score 8,798'54 MB.**

to be 8'798 MB, how can I get it?

thank you all for your help

Comment: `Return dblAns.ToString("N3", ci)`.

Comment: @Jimi to me with this comes the same format as with : 
Return dblAns.ToString("###,###,##0.00", ci)

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: `((123445568999 / 1024) / 1024).ToString("N3", ci)` prints `117,726'869`

Comment: By the way, adding all those extra characters to the format specifier is pointless. "#,0.00" would have the same effect as what you have. You don't need to specify exactly where to put every group delimiter; just that group delimiters should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59772537/setting-a-string-format-with-single-quote-or-double-format/59772915#59772915)...

To use **significant figures** instead of decimal places:

```
Public Function BytesToMegabytes(bytes As Long) As String
    Dim dblAns As Double = (bytes / 1024) / 1024

    If dblAns = 0 Then
        Return "0"
    End If

    Dim significantFigures = 3
    Dim magnitude = Math.Floor(Math.Log10(dblAns))
    Dim v As Double = 10 ^ (magnitude - significantFigures + 1)
    dblAns = Math.Floor(dblAns / v) * v

    Dim ci = New CultureInfo("")
    ci.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ","
    ci.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = "'"

    Return dblAns.ToString("#,##0.###", ci)

End Function
```

For example, `Console.WriteLine(BytesToMegabytes(9225936896))` outputs

> 8'790

If you change the line `Dim significantFigures = 3` to `Dim significantFigures = 4`, it outputs

> 8'798

Depending on the rounding you want, you may want to use `dblAns = Math.Round(dblAns / v, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) * v` instead, or perhaps `Math.Ceiling` instead of `Math.Floor`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I only need the final output in MB, but from too many positions, for example for 9225936896 to be 8'798 MB, how can I get it?
currently I score 8,798'54 MB.

Comment: @Mara There were conflicting numbers for the significant figures in the question, so I have added in how to change it. Do you also want the thousands separator to be `'`?

Comment: this already looks better to me, i wish it was a ' separator per thousand, as in the example: 8'798 MB

Comment: @Mara If you refer to my answer to your earlier question on the subject, you'll see I mentioned that you could set the value for `ci.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator`. I've edited my answer accordingly, and I guess that the decimal separator is a comma `,`.